# XCode 5 - AppleScript - How to get document in current tab

Tags: xcode, applescript, xcode5

I want to open a document in the current tab in an external application (MacVim for example). Based on a [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12306831/398861) I created an Automator service with following AppleScript code:

```
    tell application "Xcode"
        set current_document to last source document
        set current_document_path to path of current_document
    end tell

    tell application "MacVim"
        activate
        open current_document_path
    end tell
```

The issue is, that it opens the file from the first tab and not from the current tab. How can I get the path of the current tab?

Answer (score 4):

Following workaround based on [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14602063/398861) works for me.

As noted in the comment there: *This works EXCEPT if you are using the Assistant editor - then you end up with whatever happens to be in the Standard Editor. –  Lloyd Sargent* but for me it's better than the first tab.

```
on run {input, parameters}

    set current_document_path to ""

    tell application "Xcode"
        set last_word_in_main_window to (word -1 of (get name of window 1))
        if (last_word_in_main_window is "Edited") then
            display notification "Please save the current document and try again"
            -- eventually we could automatically save the document when this becomes annoying
        else
            set current_document to document 1 whose name ends with last_word_in_main_window
            set current_document_path to path of current_document
        end if
    end tell

    tell application "MacVim"
        if (current_document_path is not "") then
            activate
            open current_document_path
        end if
    end tell

    return input
end run
```

Answer (score 1):

try the following

```
tell application "Xcode"
    set docs to source documents
    if length of docs is less than 1 then
        display dialog "for ....... I need at least 1 document"
        return
    end if
    path of last item of source documents   
end tell
```